# sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, tty, pam

Unable to execute shell script, receiving the errors

The shell script I wrote connects to remote server over ssh and executes commands.

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error
```

The User with which I'm establishing ssh connection has sudo privileges on the remote server but the user account is not defined locally within the system [User is authenticating using a centralized service].

While I may have overcome the first error

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

by using "sudo -S" within the script the second error persists

I'm using sshpass utility to pass ssh password:

```
sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$IPADDRESS "COMMANDS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh -t` to force TTY allocation so that `sudo` can ask for your password.

Comment: I've tried that, didn't work.